# Class understanding: Unexpected non-void return value in void function (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm trying to figure out how classes work in swift.
I've read the classes doc on dev.apple but there's probably something essential that I don't understand. Appreciate the help and if possible, an clarification on how this is supposed to work.

I'm not able to return the json object from this function when running getData.connect

Error: `getData.swift:39:20: Unexpected non-void return value in void function`

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

public class getData: NSObject {
    public func connect(url: String, devhostname: String, hostname: String, username: String, password: String) -> Array<JSON> {
        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            hostname: .pinCertificates(
                certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(),
                validateCertificateChain: false,
                validateHost: true
            ),
            devhostname: .disableEvaluation
        ]

        let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(
            serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
        )

        var headers: HTTPHeaders = [:]

        if let authorizationHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: username, password: password) {
            headers[authorizationHeader.key] = authorizationHeader.value
        }

        sessionManager.request(url, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

            let data = response.data!
            let json = JSON(data: data)

            return json

            sessionManager.session.invalidateAndCancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You method must return an `Array<JSON>` object:

```
public func connect(url: String, devhostname: String, hostname: String, username: String, password: String) -> Array<JSON>
```

But this code is executed asyncronously:

```
sessionManager.request(url, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

    let data = response.data!
    let json = JSON(data: data)

    return json

    // this line is never executed too..
    sessionManager.session.invalidateAndCancel()
}
```

So, your method will never return the expected array. You have to remove return statement from your method declaration and manage the asyncronous response using Protocols/Listeners or CompletionHandlers.

Answer (score 0):

`.responseJSON` is asynchronous, and you can't just return your data to calling function or out of it using `return` in `.responseJSON` callback.

You may remove return type of your `connect` function, and return data back using callback of type `[JSON] -> Void`.